# looking for a browser with VR

Tags: three.js, webvr

I am looking for webbrowser for VR.
I want to test the following examples.

http://www.marzipano.net/demos.html

WebVR
Display a stereoscopic image using the WebVR API. Requires a browser with WebVR support.

I download Mozilla Nightly, but I cannot see any thing 
http://www.marzipano.net/demos/webvr/index.html

Only a blank page.

I tested 
https://threejs.org/examples/#webvr_panorama

I can see the image but I can not rotate /scroll/ any thing can be done. It is just a static image like screenshot and nothing more.

I am using
 sony xperia z3 compact -Antroid- Mozilla Firefox Nightly.
and
and

https://www.hi-shock.de/vr-shark-m4-pro-google-cardboard-2017-virtual-reality-3d-brille-/-headset-fuer-android

Any help??

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Chrome and enable WebVR through flags. For more details and other options, look at this [up to date webvr usage guide](https://github.com/Bivrost/360WebPlayer/blob/master/README.md#virtual-reality-on-desktop-and-mobile-with-webvr).

Remember to use a demo with a recent webvr (1.1) implementation. Quite a lot are legacy only. I suggest you try http://webvr.info or the demos from the page above.

Answer (score 0):

Consult [webvr.rocks](https://webvr.rocks/) for the status of WebVR support in various browsers.